# Puppeteer - Do different actions on 'load' and 'networkidle0' of same page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to do some actions as soon as page is in `load` state and some actions after waiting until `networkidle0` using puppeteer.

Is there a way to call two different functions when same page is in `waitUntil: "load"` and `waitUntil: "networkidle0"` respectively?

Comment: See if this can help you: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/custom-event.js